# Make sub-menu width automatically fit each line item on one line using CSS3 columns

Tags: html, css

I am creating a navigation menu with sub-menu items that are split into columns using CSS3. The issue I am running into is that the width is not accommodating the line items to fit on a single line due to the absolute positioning. How can I make it so that the sub-menu width will be wide enough that each line-item fits on one line automatically?

```css
nav {
  text-align:center;
}
ul {
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
  li {
    position:relative;
  }
  nav > ul > li {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:10px;
  }
    nav > ul > li:first-child {
      margin-left:0;
    }
  .sub-menu {
    padding:10px 15px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    transform:translateX(-50%);
    -webkit-column-count:2;
    -moz-column-count:2;
    column-count:2;
    -webkit-column-gap:30px;
    column-gap:30px;
    -moz-column-gap:30px;
    display:none;
  }
    nav > ul > li:hover ul {
      display:block;
    }
    .sub-menu li {
      margin-top:20px;
    }
      .sub-menu li:first-child {
        margin-top:0;
      }
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Parent One
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li>Child One</li>
          <li>Child Two</li>
          <li>Longer Child Three</li>
          <li>Child Four</li>
          <li>Child Five</li>
          <li>Longer Child Six</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Parent Two</li>
    <li>Parent Three</li>
    <li>Parent Four</li>
    <li>Parent Five</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: You can add white-space: nowrap to the style for your <li> elements, but then you'll need to play around with their widths and/or use overflow: visible

Comment: `white-space:nowrap` worked perfectly without any further adjustments. Thank you! Feel free to add as answer if you want the sweet, sweet e-points.

Comment: Just glad to help :)